# How do I add an attribute outside of combinations?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I have such a case:
I created appropriate combinations of attributes, assigned prices to them. However, I need to add another attribute that will simply add a discount to calculated price. How to do this? I don't want to add other combinations because I would have to modify many newcombinations and prices manually. I would like to make it simply possible to choose one additional attribute which will give a percentage discount to the calculated price. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think that you can use a catalog rule. Catalog rules are defined under:

```
Discount rules -> Catalog rules
```

Maybe they are named exactly differently because I don´t use Prestashop in English and I am translating from another language. Once there you need to create a new rule using the plus ("+") sign at the top right. Once at the rule creation, use "Add a new group condition" at the bottom. There you may choose product characteristics to fire the rule. Remember to click on the "+" at the right to add the condition before saving.

Comment: I tried discount rules and it is OK, but I need to show discount to customer as option/attribute. He need to see it on product page before add it to shopping cart.

Comment: Selecting a combination should update the price. If you need this discount to show more explicitly you will need to make changes to the store´s template. That will require some coding skills.